# Should we have a tag for issues to do with [scaling]?

Tags: discussion, tags

A very central issue to classic gaming, is that CRTs didn’t have pixels as we know them, and games were generally not designed with square pixels. The numerous Google hits on the topic (e.g. [Hot Hardware](https://hothardware.com/reviews/retro-gaming-enhanced-integer-scaling-in-nvidia-graphics-drivers), [PC World](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3435843/intel-adds-retro-scaling-to-ice-lake-cpus-to-make-pixel-art-games-look-more-crisp-on-modern-display.html), [PCGamesN](https://www.pcgamesn.com/amd/integer-scaling-how-to), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/retrogaming/comments/9o2r08/is_1440p_the_best_high_resolution_for_retro/), [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/integer-scaling)) shows that it is a topic of high interest amongst gamers, professionals, hardware manufacturers and more. It is therefore an issue that I believe deserves its own tag, and I hereby suggest [scaling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scaling) to be included.

There currently are two examples of posts where this might be useful:

- [Is it possible to run games in Dosbox with a better scaler / filter than the ones available in vanilla dosbox?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198584/is-it-possible-to-run-games-in-dosbox-with-a-better-scaler-filter-than-the-one) , seen 4k times.
- [How to have real full screen with Civilization in DOSBox?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48063/how-to-have-real-full-screen-with-civilization-in-dosbox/) , seen 2k times.

Comment: Tags cannot exist without applying them to questions. Do you see any questions (or have any you'd like to ask) where such a tag would apply?

Comment: I hope my added links improved the post and answered your comment. Thank you!

Comment: thanks, it certainly helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What can I do to the question to have the downvotes removed? That is: How can I improve the question enough to make it correct that the downvotes are canceled?

Comment: Downvotes are cancelled by having the people who downvoted the question reverse their votes. It's not something a moderator does

Comment: @CannedMan On Meta, downvotes are usually used to represent disagreement with the topic at hand, it's not so much about your question being 'correct' or not. In other words - to reverse downvotes, you'll have to change minds - convince the downvoters that what you're asking for is useful and relevant for the site. Note you probably won't get everyone on board, that's the way these things go sometimes. I personally think having questions to do with upscaling would be relevant to us. We do have a similar tag: [tag:backwards-compatibility] for questions to do with issues running old games.

Answer (score -1):

I think the tag *could* be useful, but it would be important to make sure that the description refers to the visual definition of the word.

I could see some people accidentally applying the tag to things such as: difficulty levels, character levels, enemies, weapons, health, in-game economics, etc...

Personally, I have had some personal difficulties with scaling being applied by emulators, connecting a classic console to modern HDTV, older PC games designed for 4:3 monitor being played on 16:9(or 21:9 or 32:9) monitors. Even the Switch [has had issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313275/does-the-nintendo-switch-work-properly-with-some-1610-monitors) in some cases.

Sometimes there's a simple console setting, emulator setting, game configuration setting, or patch/mod for the game that can help. So, the questions are probably answerable most of the time. Though, I suspect it will be a rarely used tag. Most of the questions along these lines seem to use the [monitor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) tag.

Comment: Perhaps a tightening of the tag name would solve the issues you mention, how about something like [video-upscaling]?

Comment: @Robotnik Yeah, that would probably make more sense. Something like [video-scaling], or [resolution-scaling]. I hesitate to go with "upscaling" because many of the problems aren't usually about standard upscaling, but more often about mismatched aspect ratios.